# Ajax call on page load in Node application

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Trying to make an AJAX call on page load. Below is my code snippet.

in app.js

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index',{'a':1,'b':2});
  //res.send({'a':1,'b':2});
});
```

In main.js

```
(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: '/'
         , type: 'GET'
        })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
})();
```

Ovbiously the call is going wrong here (data coming wrong). Can someone please help me to understand what concept is going wrong here ! Apreciate your help .

Comment: Can you elaborate on what specifically is going wrong? Maybe post your template and what data you are receivng? "data coming wrong" doesn't give us much to go off of.

Comment: @AndrewLavers I want data to come as {'a':1,'b':2} which I am passing through server side script.

Answer (score 0):

Change your app.js like so:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json({'a':1,'b':2});
});
```